# Is there any open source alternative to TalentLMS or Moodle?

Tags: open-source

Is there any open source alternative to TalentLMS or Moodle ?

Ideally with following features,

Roles: Admin, Learner, Instructor

Features: CPD Plan with multiple levels, Self Assesments Quiz, Instructor should provide feedback on quizes.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas by Instructure is AGPLv3 licensed.

Until earlier this year, I was the primary admin for 2 instances (plus test/beta env), did support, etc. and I still use it as a teacher and as a student.   HOWEVER... I've only used the hosted/paid for option, with all the nice 3rd party integrations and the licensing that goes with those (hosted Big Blue Button for Conferences tool, etc).

That said, the AGPL version should do what you want.  If you want to do a feature check on the hosted version, you can get a free account and trial course space (and even teach a term or two with few limits) at https://canvas.instructure.com/login/canvas

https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms

There is also Sakai, but it was bad enough that a large state university in my same town ditched it after I showed them what Canvas was doing for us...

Answer (score 0):

Please check out https://edloomio.com
Edloomio is a custom distribution of Moodle. Moodle is a free, open-source Learning Management System distributed under General Public License.

(I work for edloomio)

Comment: I want to test edloomio for a personal lms site but the github repository is empty. Do you know where is the new repository? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfied with TalentLMS and Moodle LMS services then are lots of other platforms available for LMS hosting.
If you need only an excellent platform, I recommend **DomainRacer LMS hosting**, this is one of the best platforms for hosting your learning management system (LMS) online course for your business.
**DomainRacer Tutor LMS** has great features for creating and selling online courses. It allows you to add multiple content types, including Online Quiz, Games and Participation etc.
Check the Official Bio Link => ***https://www.domainracer.com/en/lms-hosting-tutor-wordpress-courses/*** 
I used *DomainRacer LMS* to create an online course. They provide 24/7 expert support while creating online courses. They also have YouTube video solutions to assist with the creation of online courses.